# What about AngularJS typescript files after compiling?

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, web-applications, asp.net-web-api, typescript

I created a web application using angularJS with typescript in Visual Studio 2015.

1. Is it possible to add the generated .js files automatically to the project after compiling?
2. Do I have to delete the .ts files before deploying to Azure or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to add the generated .js files automatically to the project after compiling?

If the `ts` file is included with as `<TypeScriptCompile` in the project file (should happen automatically if you have TypeScript tools for Visual Studio) VS will compile and generate a js file.

> Do I have to delete the .ts files before deploying to Azure or something like that?

No. However you should have the generated `.js` files included in the project to ensure they get deployed after build.

Comment: VS generates all .js files, but I have to include them manually into the project. Is there any option to include them automatically?

Comment: `Is there any option to include them automatically` Have a glob `src/**/*.js` `<Content />` included as content in your project file